# Extract Fixed Effect and Random Effect in Dataframe

Tags: r, mixed-models

I'm using lme4 package to run mixed model. I want to extract fixed effect result and random effect result in seperate dataset, so that we can use it for further analysis. But unfortunately I could not.

E.g.

```
mixed_result<- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
```

I tried to extract fixed effect and random effect using the following method:

```
fixEffect<-fixef(mixed_result)
randEffect<-ranef(mixed_result)

View(fixEffect)
```

I tried fixef and ranef for fixed effect and random effect respectively and try to create the dataset using the result of it. But it was giving me the following error:

> Error in View : cannot coerce class ""ranef.mer"" to a data.frame

I actually want output as we get in SAS , solutionF and solutionR. But in case if it's not possible to get output like that, the coeffs of fixed and random will do.

I'll be grateful if someone can help me.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with example data and some code. `help("lmer")` demonstrates how a reproducible example could look like.

Comment: Thanks Roland for your comment. I update the question with small toy example.

Comment: `fixEffect` is a (named) vector and `randEffect` a list of data.frames. `View` can only handle data.frames. You can `print` instead. Since I don't use SAS, I have no idea how the output is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str` to see the structure of an object.

```
str(fixEffect)
# named vector, can probably be coerced to data.frame

View(as.data.frame(fixEffect))
# works just fine


str(randEffect)
# list of data frames (well, list of one data frame in this case)

View(randEffect$Subject)
```

If you had, say, slopes that also varied by `Subject`, they would go in the same `Subject` data frame as the `Subject` level intercepts. However, if intercepts also varied by some other variable `group`, with a different number of level than `Subject`, they obviously couldn't go in the same data frame. This is why a list of data frames is used, so that the same structure can generalize up for more complex models.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gregor! Your answer completely satisfies what I was asking. But is it possible to get the p-values of the coefficients for fixed and random effect models?

Comment: Probably... but not easily. I used to use `arm::se.ranef` to get the standard errors out in the same format. The `broom` package is supposed to simplify this, e.g., `broom::tidy(mixed_results, effects = "ran_modes")`, but I'm not having luck with that right now. It might be because my work computer has an older version of R. You can see how it should work [here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/issues/96).

Comment: Thanks Gregor for all your help! In my case "tidy" worked.