# Coerce fixef to data frame in R (PLM package)

Tags: r, plm

I'd like to get the fixed effects from a fixed effects panel data regression as a data frame. Something like this:

```
data("Produc", package = "plm")
zz <- plm(log(gsp) ~ log(pcap) + log(pc) + log(emp) + unemp,
data = Produc, index = c("state","year"))
View(as.data.frame(fixef(zz)))
```

Unfortunately, that last statement does not work.

My expected output would be a data frame where `state` is in the first column and the fixed effect is in the second.

I've Googled, and all I come up with is this: [Extract Fixed Effect and Random Effect in Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36136645/extract-fixed-effect-and-random-effect-in-dataframe)

Unfortunately, that answer does not seem to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to construct. First check what kind of object `fixef` returns:

```
str(fixef(zz))
#Class 'fixef'  atomic [1:48] 2.2 2.37 2.26 2.5 2.4 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "se")= Named num [1:48] 0.176 0.175 0.167 0.201 0.173 ...
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:48] "ALABAMA" "ARIZONA" "ARKANSAS" "CALIFORNIA" ...
#  ..- attr(*, "type")= chr "level"
```

This tells us that `fixef` returns an object of class 'fixef', which at its core is an atomic vector of length 48. In addition to the class attribute there are 3 attributes "se", "names" (which is usually accessable with the `names` function) and "type".

Then you can do this:

```
data.frame(state = names(fixef(zz)),
           fixef = as.vector(fixef(zz)))
#            state    fixef
#1         ALABAMA 2.201617
#2         ARIZONA 2.368088
#3        ARKANSAS 2.263016
# ...
```

`as.vector` is necessary because `data.frame` tries to coerce the S3 object into a data.frame and there is no corresponding method for `as.data.frame`.

Comment: This is obviously the right answer. Thank you. Is there some documentation for `str` output? It's always completely meaningless to me, and the CRAN docs are no help...

Comment: I don't know anything beyond the official documentation which is admittedly brief. I suggest looking at the `str` output for structures for which you know exactly what they are. I'll add an explanation for this specific example.

Comment: Returned object of `fixef` is of class c("fixef", "numeric") since a while, so this should be easier for further processing.